# How to find the Current SolutionPath in VS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins, vsx

i´m working on an addin for VS 2012..

The problem is, i need to find out the current SolutionPath to put a file in the current solution..

How can i do this?

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options:

- Using [`EnvDTE.Solution`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solution), get the `FullName` of the Solution
- Using [`IVsSolution`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution), call [`GetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolution.getproperty) to get the [`VSPROPID_SolutionFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.__vspropid) (or `VSPROPID_SolutionDirectory` if you want the directory)
- Get the MSBuild project for the Solution and get the `$(SolutionDir)` property.

Comment: If you want to use the first option (`EnvDTE.Solution`), I should point out that this is passed into the add-in in `OnConnection` and assigned to `_applicationObject`. You can then use `_applicationObject.Solution.FullName` to get what you want.